# escape sequence for all the keyboard keys in python

Tags: python

i am using telnetlib in python...
i have used '\r' for enter key,'\t' for TAB.
as same as this scenario i want the char sequence for SHIFT,PAGE UP,PAGE DOWN,F1,F2...F12.
pleas help me regarding this issue as i have to use all this keyboard keys in my code.

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
tn.write("\r") #this is for enter
tn.write("\t") # this is for tab

#what should be here to other keys..pls

print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: '\r' represents the carriage return character in ASCII ( `len("\r")` is 1). There aren't characters for those other keys, so you need to work out the sequence of bytes the server expects. Shift is a modifier key, i.e. Shift-a makes one 'A' byte, but shift by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: i got value for key f4 = '\x1b4', f3 = \x1b3, f5 = \x1b5, f6 = \x1b6 but i cant get logic behind this values.@Thomas K: The server expects a "shift + F1" key, how to know what sequence of bytes are generated using this "shift + F1" event?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all key-presses result in one or more bytes being sent over the wire.  This is really about terminal emulation, since control keys are "meant" to be interpreted by the terminal device (or emulator).

Different terminal types define different keys and map them to different byte values in the stream.  For example, some terminals have F11 and F12, and some don't.  Some define Ctrl+F keys, Shift+F keys, Alt+F keys, Command+F keys; others don't.  And different terminals map these keys to completely different byte sequences over the wire.  The issue is the same when it comes to arrow keys and cursor-mode keys like insert.

You may find that certain keys are trapped by the client and not transmitted at all, or that non-keyboard events (such as resizing the terminal window with the mouse) transmit terminal escape sequences.

Comment: thanks for your elaboration but i am really stucked here and i cant get how to find byte sequence for shift+F1.i got this two links for more KT and i got the keys like F! to F12 but still cant convert SHIFT + F1.or say i didn't get the logic behind it..links are. http://www.asciitable.com/ and http://coding.derkeiler.com/pdf/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2006-04/msg02566.pdf

Comment: Shift+F1 may be captured by the terminal program, or even the desktop environment, and not transmitted at all.  If you add a trace to report every byte received, and then try Shift+F1, you will see what byte sequence, if any, corresponds to it.  You may see nothing.  The exact byte sequence will depend on the terminal type being emulated.

Comment: Also, if you code your solution according to the particular byte sequences you observe, your code will blow up when another user, using a different terminal type, tries to use your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go with thistelnet client : https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2000-August/msg00070.html

Comment: 404 – not found